# How to have a global variable accessible across all packages

Tags: go

I have a main.go file which has:

```
// running the router in port 9000
func main() {
    router,Global := routers.InitApp()
    fmt.println(Global)
    router.RunTLS(":9000" , "domain.crt" , "domain.key")
}
```

In `router.InitMap` I want to declare a global variable which can be accessed throughout my application anywhere. Is is possible? I tried:

```
func InitApp() (*gin.Engine,string) {
        var Global= "myvalue"           
        router := gin.New()
        return router,Global


}
```

But I can't access the variable `Global` even in the same package.

Comment: why you want to do that? You will have a hard time testing stuff.

Comment: I want to get the configuration data for my application once when the application starts. This is returned via a rest API. for eg: database hostname , username etc.

Comment: Then declare the variable outside the function `InitApp` in first place: `var Global string` and then assign a value to it when ready.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

declare a variable at the top level - outside of any functions:

```
var Global = "myvalue"

func InitApp() (string) {
        var Global= "myvalue"
        return Global

}
```

Since the name of the variable starts with an uppercase letter, the variable will be available both in the current package through its name - and in any other package when you import the package defining the variable and qualify it with the package name as in: `return packagename.Global`.

Here's another illustration (also in the Go playground: https://play.golang.org/p/h2iVjM6Fpk):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var greeting = "Hello, world!"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(greeting)
}
```

See also Go Tour: "Variables" https://tour.golang.org/basics/8 and "Exported names" https://tour.golang.org/basics/3.

Comment: I noticed that if I get the global variable from a function's return value. Everytime this function is called. For eg: `var Global = InitApp

func InitApp() (string) {
        var Global= "myvalue"
        return Global

}` everytime I try to access Global , InitApp is called. Is there anyway I can  avoid this? I want that Global variable is fetched only once.

Comment: make sure to call the function with (), for example: var Global = InitApp() See https://play.golang.org/p/jdsFqFVxVi for a runnable example.

Comment: @aaj, it is old thread but someone might need an answer: you should use init functions to set once a variable by a function. var greeting string func init(){greeting= InitApp()}

Comment: For me, an Exported ( Global) Variable in `main package` is not accessible, from other packages. but the same time,Exported Variable from package is accessible from main (`packagename.VariableName`)

Comment: make sure that you don't initialise `greeting := "Hello, world!"` inside a function again. Just use the `=` to set the value

Answer (score 12):

It is better to use the init function for initialisation of global variables. It also will be processed only once even in multiply includes of this package. https://play.golang.org/p/0PJuXvWRoSr

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

var Global string 

func init() { 
        Global = InitApp()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Global)
}

func InitApp() (string) {
        return "myvalue"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution:

define the global variable in other package with Set and Get, similar with class set in python

the good part is that you can set global variables in any package, the bad part is that you can mess up the global variables if you use Set not carefully

https://play.golang.org/p/egApePP7kPq

first define global variable

````
    -- globalvar/globalvar.go --
    package globalvar
    
    import "fmt"
    
    var Glbv int
    
    func Set(b int) {
        Glbv = b
    }
    
    func Get() int {
        return Glbv
    }
    
    func Pr() {
        fmt.Printf("inside globarvar = %v \n", Glbv)
    } ```
then you can change the global variable in another package
````

```
-- otherpackage/otherpackage.go --
package otherpackage

import (
    "fmt"
    "play.ground/globalvar"
)

func Bar() {
    globalvar.Set(3)
}

func Prtf() {
    var cc = globalvar.Get()
    fmt.Printf("inside otherpackage globalvar=%v \n", cc)
}
```

```
main function
```

```
package main

import (
    "play.ground/globalvar"
    "play.ground/otherpackage"
)

func main() {
    globalvar.Pr()
    otherpackage.Prtf()
    globalvar.Set(2)
    globalvar.Pr()
    otherpackage.Prtf()
    otherpackage.Bar()
    globalvar.Pr()
    otherpackage.Prtf()
}
```

```
here is the result
    inside globarvar = 0 
    inside otherpackage globalvar=0 
    inside globarvar = 2 
    inside otherpackage globalvar=2 
    inside globarvar = 3 
    inside otherpackage globalvar=3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like writing a function to initialise the global variable as:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

func initialise() string {
    CommonVariable = "global_variable"
    return CommonVariable
}

var  CommonVariable string

func main() {
     
     initialise()
     fmt.Println(CommonVariable)
}
```

If you want to take input from user and then initialise it to global variable, just change the line CommonVariable="myvalue" in initialise() function with "Scanf" statement like this:

```
func initialise() string {
     fmt.Scanln(&CommonVariable)
     return CommonVariable
}
```