# Global variables from different files Golang

Tags: go

I have two different files: (1) /common/handler.go and (2) main.go.

In the ***(/common/handler.go)*** file, I have declared

```
var db *sql.DB
var err error
```

as global variables (at the top level, below import). Now, I want to use these two variables in my ***main.go*** file because I have this line of code in my main() function:

```
db, err = sql.Open("mysql","username:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test123")
```

What should I do in order for Go to understand that I was referring to that db and err variables? Am I even doing this the right way? If not, please let me know the best solution.

The reason I split into these two files because I want to make the code cleaner.

Basically, main() in main.go contains

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.HandleFunc("/", common.login)
....
```

and handler.go contains all the messy stuff.

Thanks,

Comment: duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655730/how-to-have-a-global-variable-accessible-across-all-packages-in-golang

Comment: @Jackyjjc it looks different to me as my global variables already declared outside but still not working.

Comment: Go is not _file_-based but _package_ based. And visabaility between packages is based on identifiers being export (capital name) or unexported (lowercase). Take the Tour of Go for details.

Answer (score 1):

*"I want to use these two variables in my main.go"* You can't because they are unexported, ergo you need to [export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) them.

*"What should I do in order for Go to understand that I was referring to that db and err variables?"* You need to [qualify](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers) them. It's no different from you telling Go with `sql.Open` that you're referring to the function `Open` that's declared in the package `database/sql`.

---

Also I recommend you take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. Clearly, I still have to go back to basic again.